# can't use the page_test method to check pagination

Tags: posts, pagination, conditional-content

I've tried to follow the example for [Testing for paginated Pages](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) but i don't know why it isn't working. i put it in the single.php file for post detection. i don't know why the page_test is broken. example code here:

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

    <div id="content" class="narrowcolumn" role="main">
    <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <div <?php post_class(); ?> id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>">
            <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
            <div style="margin-top:5px">
<div style="padding:5px; float:left; margin-right:50px;"><fb:share-button href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="url" type="button_count"></fb:share-button></div>

        <?php    
        $page_test = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
        if ( ! $page_test || $page_test < 2 ) {

            something here...

            <?php } else { ?>

            another here...

            <?php } ?>
```

Comment: global $wp_query;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the above solution i tried already.

Never mind, i solved it, even i don't know why. if some body knows...:
this:

```
// not working
    $paged = get_query_var( 'paged' ) ? get_query_var( 'paged' ) : false;
    if ( $paged === false ) {
```

didn't worked, but this:

```
// works
    $paged = get_query_var( 'page' ) ? get_query_var( 'page' ) : false;
    if ( $paged === false ) {
```

did work. the difference is "page" instead of "paged". i don't know why everywhere i looked i've found the code with "paged" and it didn't worked (even it the conditional tags page in the codex!), but [here](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/page-pagination-doesnt-seem-to-wor), in a simple topic i found it.

nevertheless, it is solved.

Comment: ehm yea. both codes are _exactly_ the same...

Comment: sorry, fixed the difference between them

Comment: n/p. I updated the codex with your answer. I'm sure i also ran into this once. I also updated your answer, because the "true" on false would be missleading. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: you're more then welcome. for the greater good ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You need to either add `global $wp_query;`

```
global $wp_query;
$page_test = $wp_query->get( 'paged' );
```

or use `get_query_var();`

```
$page_test = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
```

Comment: Just updated Asafs answer... the `true` on false is a little missleading.